# People hate me for concentrating on work

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, management, communication, project-management

I am an introvert in the sense that I like to work more and talk less.

This does not go well with my colleagues in the same room, because they like to gossip for the whole day and not work. Their talking is breaking my concentration. What should I do?

Comment: What does "This does not go well with my colleagues.." mean? Are you making them mad? Or do you just not fit in with the group dynamic?

Comment: @dfundako I am actually quite nice when talking to people.When i am interacting with other members in different room , I GET ALONG with them.But in this room the problem is that my rate of taking per time is less that those of my same room.What should i do?

Comment: How is that in any way a problem? Nothing you are saying shows that your colleagues "hate you for concentrating on work"

Comment: @debo.stackoverflow It doesn't sound like there is a problem. You are getting your work done, while whatever they are or aren't doing is not your concern. Can you add some more details about what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @dfundako One day one of the collegues told me why do i not talk much?(In her case technically i should talk at a gap of 10 mins !!!).This is the problem.What should i do or reply?

Comment: @Celada I think they want me to talk more when i really want to work more and talk less.What to do?This may seem stupid but it is affecting me. :(

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes i have tried talking with them preferably in gaps of 1hr.And it goes well.As normal as office banter can be.Its just that the rate of talking is less when me is concerned with the others

Comment: Is the actual problem that you're not socializing enough, or that because you're spending more time working your productivity is enough higher that it's making your coworkers look bad?

Comment: @DanNeely Yes You are correct.I am just a normal worker who does his job and every 2 or 3 hrs when i get mentally exhaustive I DO talk.But in this company besides some people,many others are constantly gossiping and not working.My rate of talking is less but i think it is normal.Its their rate of talking i think is abnormal to be honest really.What to do? :(

Comment: Most likely the colleague that said "Why don't you talk much?" asked that not to criticize, but to indirectly encourage. Don't worry about your "rate" of talking or "gaps". Talk about work as needed and participate in banter as desired, or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr**: you don't have to participate in office banter if you don't want to.

I think you are seeing a problem here where the isn't one. You like to concentrate on your work without talking. That's perfectly fine. They like to work socially? That's perfectly fine too. Plus, if their socializing is keeping them from getting work done, that's not your problem.

> One day one of the collegues told me why do i not talk much?(In her case technically i should talk at a gap of 10 mins !!!).This is the problem.What should i do or reply?

Your colleague requests that you talk every 10 minutes on a schedule? That sounds ridiculous. You don't have to take this seriously at all unless it comes from your manager.

You should reply that you prefer to concentrate on your tasks while you work and ask this colleague to please not disturb you unless they have work-related questions to ask you or work-related information to share. If this doesn't work, you can try wearing headphones: that's a well-known signal that a colleague prefers to work alone unless a work-related interruption is justified.

Comment: Ok will try wearing headphones as i cant say that i prefer concentrating rather than gossiping to other members or i will make them feel inferior unnecessary.

Comment: Totally agree, so long as they are leaving you alone it's ok, no reason to think they hate you.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with preferring to work than to socialize. Yet your colleagues are objecting to your behaviour. Why? There are a few possibilities. One you have come up with is "They hate me for concentrating on work." Let's try some others:

- they are momentarily irritated with me when I brush off their attempts to chat
- their feelings are hurt when I say I couldn't care less about their weekend plans, or their children, or their dog, or these cute new shoes
- they feel criticized when I tell them we are here to work not to chat
- they are offended when their conversations are called gossip by someone who refuses to join in

I bet you can come up with a few more if you try. See the difference?

Try responding **once** to chitchat from them. Laugh at the joke, "aw" at the baby or puppy, admire the shoes or the plans. Answer with a single sentence when you are asked these sorts of things. Then get back to work. Smile at them. Indicate that you enjoyed the moment of relaxation with them. You don't need to do 8 hours a day of it, or 10 minutes every hour, but in almost all jobs, a few moments a day of collegiality is actively encouraged. It helps teams pull together and support each other.

Don't tell them you think they spend the whole day gossiping, or that they should work more, or anything else that might be perceived as judgmental. Ask yourself, "how would I act if I liked these people and enjoyed their company?" Then ask yourself what is keeping you from acting like that for a few minutes each day. Consider doing it, but more importantly, learn about yourself and your workplace from your answer to those questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer."Laugh at the joke, "aw" at the baby or puppy, admire the shoes or the plans. Answer with a single sentence when you are asked these sorts of things. Then get back to work. Smile at them".I will try to implement them.